# How to change default aesthethics in ggplot2 for a group

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to override the default settings in creating an error plot. For example, I have two different "Levels" in the following snippet:

```
plot<-ggplot(df, aes(x=variable, y=value, colour=Levels, group=Levels)) + 
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=value-se, ymax=value+se), colour="black", width=.1, position=pd) +
    geom_line(position=pd) +
    geom_point(position=pd, size=3, shape=21, fill="white"))
```

I want to plot a black and white display, with the `geom_line` displaying continuous and dashed lines for the two group members, and `geom_point` shading black for one and white for the other Level.

So far I cannot get `lty=c("1","2")` or `fill=c("white", "black")` to work.

Comment: How about do some code formatting easy for the answerer.

Comment: Why do you map `colour=Levels` if you want a black and white graph? You should map `fill=Level, linetype=Level` and then use `scale_fill_manual` and `scale_shape_manual`.

Comment: @user3218416 If you worked out an answer for your question, you should post the solution as an answer (and then you can accept it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    plot<-ggplot(mdf, aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=Levels,   
    group=Levels,linetype=Levels))+ 
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=value-se, ymax=value+se), colour="black", width=.1,   
    position=pd) +
    geom_line(position=pd, colour="black")+scale_shape_manual(values=c("1","2"))+
    geom_point(position=pd, size=3, shape=21, colour="black")+
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("white","black")))
```